# Scroll to section by clicking list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a scroll to the corresponding .cinematography_box when I click on a item on the list of the sidebar, I have with this markup:

It would be like, first item on the list > goto > first .cinematography_box div and so on on the second, third and etc

What would be the best way to achieve this?

```
            <div id="sidebar" class="clearfix">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a id="aboutlink" href="javascript:void(0)" >CINEMATOGRAPHY LIST</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">FIRST ITEM</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">SECOND ITEM</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">THIR ITEM</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

                <div id="gallery" class="cinematography clearfix">

                    <div class="cinematography_box clearfix">
                        <div class="cinematography_item">
                        </div>
                        <div class="cinematography_info">
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cinematography_box clearfix">
                        <div class="cinematography_item">
                        </div>
                        <div class="cinematography_info">
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cinematography_box clearfix" >
                        <div class="cinematography_item">
                        </div>
                        <div class="cinematography_info">
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define each element like that:

```
<li data-target="one">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)">THIR ITEM</a>
</li>

<div class="cinematography_info" data-pos="one">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

And using jQuery you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function() {
       scrollTo($(this).attr("data-target"));
    });
});


function scrollTo(target){
    var tagScroll = $(".cinematography_info[data-pos='"+ target+"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: tagScroll .offset().top},'slow');
}
```

See the example that i've made:
http://jsfiddle.net/NfwEv/9/

Comment: With your edit the error is: "Cannot read property 'top' of undefined "

Comment: @red_alert why do you introduce new syntax, if there is already a standart with having `href="#target"` at the link and `id="target"` at the target? jquery still can be used in addition to do some eye candy. your way  will break accessibility.

Comment: @diego See the example at jsfiddle, I've forgot to change de function name. Now it's working and you can see it http://jsfiddle.net/NfwEv/9/

Comment: @diego To keep the standarts and don't break the accessibility you could see this example: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

First, give your three `div` tags ID's, say `item1`, `item2`, `item3`.

That way, you can change your `a` tags to be:

```
<li>
    <a href="#item1">FIRST ITEM</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#item2">SECOND ITEM</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#item3">THIR ITEM</a>
</li>
```

Comment: For me it doesn´t answer the OP question at all... not even close at a solution, it´s this a joke answer?

Comment: @fxg Yes it does? He wants his `a` tags to navigate to the different `div`s on the page on click. My code does **exactly that**

Comment: @fxg i'm also interrested why this should not answer the question?